# Direct sum of multiplier algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, multiplier-algebra

Consider a collection of $C^*$-algebras $\{A_i\}_{i \in I}$. We can form the direct sum $$\bigoplus_{i \in I}^{c_0} A_i:= \left\{(a_i)_{i \in I} \in \prod_{i\in I} A_i: \lim_{i \in I} \|a_i\| = 0\right\}$$
which is an ideal in the $C^*$-algebra
$$\bigoplus_{i \in I}^{\ell^\infty} A_i:= \left\{(a_i)_{i \in I} \in \prod_{i\in I} A_i: \sup_{i \in I} \|a_i\| <\infty\right\}.$$
Given a $C^*$-algebra $A$, denote its multiplier algebra by $M(A)$. One possible realisation of the multiplier algebra is by setting $M(A):= \mathcal{L}_A(A)$, the adjointable operators when we view $A$ as a (right) Hilbert $C^*$-module over itself.

I believe I have proven that
$$M\left(\bigoplus_{i \in I}^{c_0}A_i\right) \cong \bigoplus_{i \in I}^{\ell^\infty} M(A_i)\cong M\left(\bigoplus_{i \in I}^{\ell^\infty}A_i\right)$$
but I can't find a reference for this statement. So, is my assertion true?

---

Here is a proof sketch:
We use the implementation of the multiplier $C^*$-algebra as adjointable operators. We then have natural maps
$$M\left(\bigoplus_{i \in I}^{c_0}A_i\right) \to \bigoplus_{i \in I}^{\ell^\infty} M(A_i): t \mapsto  (\iota_i ^* t\iota_i)_{i \in I}$$ where
$\iota_i: A_i \hookrightarrow \bigoplus_{i \in I}^{c_0} A_i$ is the inclusion map and
$$\bigoplus_{i \in I}^{\ell^\infty} M(A_i) \to M\left(\bigoplus_{i \in I}^{c_0}A_i\right) : (t_i)_{i \in I} \mapsto [(a_i)_i \mapsto (t_i(a_i))]$$
These are easily checked to be $*$-isomorphisms that are inverse to each other, and this establishes the isomorphism $M\left(\bigoplus_{i \in I}^{c_0}A_i\right) \cong \bigoplus_{i \in I}^{\ell^\infty} M(A_i)$. The other isomorphism is shown similarly.

Comment: The isomorphism you sketch is correct. The one you are not sketching is incorrect. There are in general a lot more multiplier on $\ell^\infty-\bigoplus_i A_i$ than on $c_0-\bigoplus_i A_i$.

Comment: @Jamie Gabe Thanks. Where does the proof break down in the $\ell^\infty$-case?

Comment: In your sketch proof, I do not (immediately) see why: (a) $\iota_i^* t \iota_i$ need be adjointable; and (b) why are the two maps mutual inverses?  It seems like more argument is needed, and it's here the $\ell^\infty$ case would be different.

Comment: Sorry, more to the point, what _is_ $\iota_i^*$?  Because $\iota_i$ is a map between Hilbert $C^*$-modules over _different_ algebras, so I don't really know what adjointable or the adjoint would mean in such a situation.

Comment: @MatthewDaws Yes, you are right. We should replace it by the projection onto the $i$-th component.

Comment: @MatthewDaws Thanks! You are right. I filled in some details. If $\pi_i$ denotes the projection on the $i$-th component, then $\pi_i t^* \iota_i$ is an adjoint for $\pi_i t \iota_i$ (which is also what we need since we want the map to preserve the involution). To show that the second map is left inverse to the first map, we must show an equality of two maps on the $c_0$-direct sum. And here we can use  the fact that the algebraic direct sum is dense in the $c_0$-direct sum, which is no longer true for the $\ell^\infty$-direct sum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try to flesh out your "sketch".  Set $A=c_0-\oplus_i A_i$ and consider this as a Hilbert $C^*$-module over itself.  Let $\iota_i:A_i\rightarrow A$ be the inclusion, and $\jmath_i:A\rightarrow A_i$ the left inverse to $\iota_i$.  These are both non-degenerate $*$-homomorphisms, and so extend to unital $*$-homomorphisms $\overline\iota_i:M(A_i)\rightarrow M(A)$ and $\overline\jmath_i:M(A)\rightarrow M(A_i)$.  Also, notice that by definition of the $A$-valued inner-product on $A$,
$$ (b|\iota_i(a)) = \iota_i\big( (\jmath_i(b)|a) \big)
\qquad (b\in A, a\in A_i). $$

Given $T\in M(A)$ set $T_i = \overline\jmath_i(T)\in M(A_i)$.  By definition, $T_i(\jmath_i(a)) = \jmath_i(T(a))$ for $a\in A$, and as $\jmath_i$ is a $*$-homomorphism, also $T_i^*(\jmath_i(a)) = \jmath_i(T^*(a))$.  For $a\in A_i$ and $b=(b_j)\in A$,
$$ (T\iota_i(a)|b) = (\iota_i(a)|T^*(b))
= \iota_i\big( (a|\jmath_i(T^*(b))) \big)
= \iota_i\big( (a|T_i^*(\jmath_i(b))) \big) $$
while
$$ (\iota_i T_i(a)|b) = \iota_i\big( (T_i(a)|\jmath_i(b)) \big)
= \iota_i\big( (a|T_i^*(\jmath_i(b))) \big). $$
Thus $T\iota_i = \iota_iT_i$ for each $i$.

As the linear span of the images of the $\iota_i$ are dense in $A$, it now follows that
$$ T(a) = \sum_i T\iota_i\jmath_i(a) = \sum_i \iota_i\big( T_i\jmath_i(a) \big), $$
and the isomorphism $M(A) \cong \ell^\infty-\oplus_i M(A_i)$ now follows.

---

I actually find arguing using Hilbert $^*$-modules a bit cumbersome.  Instead, let $A_i\subseteq\mathcal B(H_i)$ non-degenerately, for each $i$, for some suitable Hilbert space $H_i$.  Set $H = \oplus_i H_i$, so naturally $A$ acts non-degenerately on $H$.  Set $B=\ell^\infty-\oplus_i A_i$, so also $B$ acts non-degenerately on $H$.  I'll now consider $B$, but much the same argument works for $A$.

We know that $M(B)\subseteq B''\subseteq \mathcal B(H)$, and indeed
$$ M(B) = \big\{ T\in B'' : Tb, bT\in B \ (b\in B) \big\}. $$
Given $b=(b_i)\in B$ and $\xi=(\xi_i)\in H$, by definition, $b(\xi) = (b_i(\xi_i))$.  As such, with $p_i\in\mathcal B(H)$ the projection onto the factor $H_i$, we see that $b p_i = p_i b$ so $p_i\in B'$.

Thus, any $T\in M(B)\subseteq B''$ commutes with each $p_i$.  By linearity and continuity, there is $(T_i) \in \ell^\infty-\oplus_i \mathcal B(H_i)$ with $T(\xi) = (T_i(\xi_i))$ for each $\xi\in H$.  Using the inclusions $A_i\rightarrow B$, we can now show that each $T_i\in M(A_i)$.

We have hence showed that $M(B) \cong \ell^\infty-\oplus_i M(A_i)$.  [This seems surprising to me, but I believe this 2nd argument.]

Comment: Thanks! So the second isomorphism holds after all, but my approach did not work.

Comment: This gives nice examples of inclusions $A \subsetneq B$ where $M(A) = M(B)$.

Comment: Oh, I was wrong in saying that $\ell^\infty-\oplus A_i$ had a different multiplier algebra! Yikes! You're absolutely right, Matt! One can also deduce this from the fact that if $A \subseteq B \subseteq M(A)$ are inclusions of two-sided closed ideals (so that the composition is the canonical inclusion $A\subseteq M(A)$), then $M(A) = M(B)$. This is an easy consequence of the universal property of multiplier algebras. One can apply this to $A = c_0-\oplus A_i$ and $B = \ell^\infty-\oplus_Ai$ once one has convinced themselves that $M(A) = \ell^\infty -\oplus M(A_i)$.

Comment: @JamieGabe That's a very nice observation, and a much easier way to get the result!